# Xslt producing Xslt: setting root namespaces

Tags: .net, xslt, xml-namespaces

I use XSLT as a "code generator" for various components, including other XSLT. For example, I have a query that produces an XML output of MSSQL sys.columns rows for a table, and wish to produce an XSLT that includes a table with a column for each row.

So I want to produce the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:format="urn:qbo3-formatting" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I generate the XSLT above with something like this 'generator' XSLT:

```
<xsl:element name="xsl:stylesheet">
  <xsl:attribute name="version">1.0</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="format" namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" >urn:qbo3-formatting</xsl:attribute>
  ...
</xsl:element>
```

The problem is that this 'generator' XSLT produces:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xml:format="urn:qbo3-formatting" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the `xml:format` instead of the desired `xmlns:format`.

According to W3C, 'xmlns' is reserved and bound to 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/'. If I attempt to create the format attribute above using this namespace, I get an error:

`Elements and attributes cannot belong to the reserved namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/'.`

Any suggestions on a work-around?

Thanks in advance,

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is exactly the main usecase for the [`<xsl:namespace-alias>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-namespace-alias) instruction**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:format="some:format"
 xmlns:xxx="xxx">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="xxx"
                      result-prefix="xsl"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xxx:stylesheet version="1.0"
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:format="some:format"
     >

      <xxx:template match="node()|@*">
        <xxx:copy>
          <xxx:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xxx:copy>
      </xxx:template>
    </xxx:stylesheet>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted result (a new stylesheet with all wanted attributes and namespaces) is produced:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:format="some:format">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**: Avoid using `xsl:element` and prefer `xsl:namespace-alias` whenever the transformation should generate another XSLT stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<xsl:element name="xsl:stylesheet">
  <xsl:attribute name="version">1.0</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:namespace name="format" select="'urn:qbo3-formatting'"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Alternately, instead of explicitly outputting an XML namespace, allow XSLT to autogenerate the XML namespaces once nodes of that namespace get used.  If no elements are using `urn:qbo3-formatting`, then the namespace declaration isn't necessary.